# Mvvcross WithFallback on xamarin ios

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, xamarin.ios-binding

i'm using MvvmCross on xamarin iOS. I'm using fluent for the bindings on the ViewModel and json. I wanted to try the WithFallback() function, but when the property on my ViewModel (string in this case), comes null or empty, it doesn't do anything. I tried this:

```
//This works
this.BindLanguage(Header1, "Title");

/*  This works when vm.Message is not null or empty, 
/*  else print nothing, but don't call the WithFallback function 
*/
set.Bind(myLbl).For(view => view.Text).To(vm => vm.Message).WithFallback("Something");
set.Apply();
```

And another question is how i can bind that fallback with a property of the viewmodel or json. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fallback` will only be used if the binding fails, not if the property exists and is null or whatever.

You can read more about this in the [official documentation](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/data-binding#fallback-values).

In your case, I would suggest you use a ValueConverter, something like this will work:

```
public class MyValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<string, string>
{
    protected override string Convert(string value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? value : "Something";
    }

    protected override string ConvertBack(string value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And then your binding:

```
set.Bind(myLbl).For(view => view.Text).To(vm => vm.Message).WithConversion<MyValueConverter>();
```